# Bokeh tool change icon

Tags: python, icons, bokeh, toolbar

I cannot seem to change the icon of any tool on Bokeh Toolbar. To avoid any confusion I am running Bokeh v3.2.0 and all references and links below will be in the context of 3.2.0, though the problem appears to exist in earlier versions (I have tested 2.4.*

Here is what [official documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/tools.html#customizing-tools-icon) states:

> It’s also possible to change a tool icon using the icon keyword. You can pass:
>
> A well known icon name
>
> ```
> plot.add_tools(BoxSelectTool(icon="box_zoom"))
> ```
>
> A CSS selector
>
> ```
> plot.add_tools(BoxSelectTool(icon=".my-icon-class"))
> ```
>
> An image path
>
> ```
> plot.add_tools(BoxSelectTool(icon="path/to/icon"))
> ```

Here is a minimal example of the problem I have (in Jupyter for simplicity):

```
'''  Minimal example of the problem
'''
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.models import BoxSelectTool
output_notebook()
x = list(range(11))
y = x

# create three plots
p = figure(
    width=300,
    height=300,
)
p.circle(x, y, size=12, alpha=0.8, color="#53777a")
p.add_tools(BoxSelectTool(icon="box_zoom")) # This fails

show(p)
```

This produces an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/username/workspace/box_zoom'
```

Based on the documentation I would expect the above code to pick a built-in icon based on a "well known name". In fact the line of code is literally taken from the documentation.

I also tried:

```
p.add_tools(BoxSelectTool(icon=".my-icon-class"))
```

.. hoping that I can then just save icon in my static folder and sort the rest out in CSS. That also fails with the same error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/username/workspace/.my-icon-class'
```

I searched the interwebz extensively but nobody appears to have be having the same problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your post. This is a bug and because of your question there is an open [Issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/13257) in the bokeh project which will be solved in the upcoming release 3.3.0.

Comment: Thanks @mosc9575! This is brilliant. Just wanted to use this opportunity to say that Bokeh is awesome. Keep up the good work.